# how much energy is required to create a sound with constant frequency and amplitude?

Tags: power, sound, energy, source

Ok, this is a theoretical question, (Forgive my poor English, I am not a native speaker).

Lets assume that I have a power-source with p unknown.
this power-source provides energy to a speaker to produce a sound with constant frequency, f, and constant amplitude, a, given in decibels.

We also assume that all of the energy goes to create the sound (there is no heat or other "noise" disturbances).

So the question is - what is p?

(to simplify the question - I know that the sound is 60 dB with constant frequency - lets say 300 hrz and I need to know how much power I need to provide to the system for that to work)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The power required to achieve a specific sound pressure level from a speaker depends entirely on how efficient that particular speaker is.  The manufacturer usually rates the speaker sensitivity as a specific sound pressure level on axis with the speaker at a specified distance from the speaker with a specific power level into the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible to answer with the information given. First, that 60dB is meaningless without a weighting and distance from the speaker. Even then, unless you're in a free field, acoustics and environmental factors come into play. Finally, it depends on the sensitivity of the speaker, efficiency of the amplifier, and rest of the electronic system. Figuring out how much power it takes is not a trivial or worthwhile task. In the real world, give it twice as much as you think it will take, and let physics work out the rest.

Comment: Ok, so I read the two answers and yet I find the answers a bit confusing, because when I look at the volume button on the computer speakers, it measures in dBs. How can one estimates the volume in dBs if it is depended on the location of the hearer?

Comment: What does it say? Speaker sensitivity is often measured at 1W and 1m.

Comment: @IlanZack a fader or volume control is at 0dB when it is not attenuating (full volume). dB attenuation is not directly related to dB sound pressure level, but additive - if your system is generating 70dB SPL when the fader is at 0dB, moving the fader down to -20dB should mean your system produces 50dB instead.

Answer (score 1):

If by 60dB you mean 60 dB SPL (sound pressure level) then the power emitted from an [isotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropic_radiator) loudspeaker 1 metre away will be 71dB of sound power. If the distance doubled to 2m, to hear the same 60dB SPL requires that the speaker produces a sound power level of 77 dB.

Next comes directivity, Q take a look at this: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [bnoack.com](http://www.bnoack.com/graphics/Q_eighthspace.jpg))</sub>

This speaker has a directivity of 8 and if this were swapped for the isotropic speaker, at 1 metre distance an SPL of 60dB requires a sound power of 62dB.

So immediately there are two ends of the scale. On one hand it might be an isotropic emitter requiring a sound power of 71 dB or it might be a speaker tucked away in a corner of a room - this needs to produce 9 dB less power or, in real terms about tenth of the wattage.

Directivity, Q versus frequency. Here is a quote: -

> Loudspeakers also vary widely in directivity versus frequency. A
>   speaker may actually have a Q of 12 at 2kHz, it is likely that the
>   directivity value would drop to a Q of 4 at 500Hz, and as low as a Q
>   of 1 at 125Hz.

Taken from [this](http://www.bnoack.com/index.html?http&&&www.bnoack.com/audio/directivity.html) website.

Next, you have to factor in speaker efficiency. Here is another quote: -

> - Typical home loudspeakers have sensitivities of about 85 to 95 dB for 1 W @ 1 m—an efficiency of 0.5–4%.
> - Sound reinforcement and public address loudspeakers have sensitivities of perhaps 95 to 102 dB for 1 W @ 1 m—an efficiency of
>     4–10%.
> - Rock concert, stadium PA, marine hailing, etc. speakers generally have higher sensitivities of 103 to 110 dB for 1 W @ 1 m—an efficiency
>     of 10–20%.

Taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker#Efficiency_vs._sensitivity). The above is covering a speaker efficiency range of 40:1 at the extremes.

Then you have to consider the type of amplifier you are using. It may be a class A (<50% efficiency) amplifier (as favoured by audiphiles, god bless 'em) or it might be a class D type (maybe 90% efficient).

These are all factors.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you're asking: how much power is 60dB? Decibels come in various flavours, they're only measuring the log of a ratio with a reference. Acoustic decibels are usually calculated in terms of Sound Pressure Level, or dB SPL. And that question cannot be answered with SPLs. 
$$L_{dB} = 10 \log_{10} \frac{X}{X_{ref}}$$

dB SPL are actually a measure of what pressure is exerted onto a person's ear, or in Pa (N/m²). You can **estimate** the amount of power emitted from a source given how much pressure there is on that person's ear, and how far they are from the source by assuming a isotropic distribution of the sound in the following way:
$$\text{dB SWL} = \text{dB SPL} + 10 \log_{10}\left(4\pi r^2\right)$$
([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_power#Estimating_sound_power_level_from_sound_pressure_level))
However isotropy never happens and actual sound distribution is subjected to the environment (wind or rain, objects that reflect sound, ...).

Still, this is the power of an ideal source (note the Sound Power decibel, compared to 1 picowatt). In practice, the speaker will have some gain associated to it (or rather, attenuation) which is the result of the very small efficiency of that electricity-sound converter, and the driver of that speaker as well. Eventually, this would give you the "power in" for your "sound pressure" figure. But that's a whole lot more data to account for, giving approximate results!

Finally, note that frequency jumps in for 1) the effect of that sound pressure variation on the person: the ears are sensors which have their own mechanical frequeny response (and hence bandwidth), so depending on the frequency pain levels for example will be different 2) The gains/attenuations of the speaker and speaker driver depend on the frequency (and actually the attenuation of air as well).

Answer (score 0):

Power is not the same thing as energy - it is energy *per unit time*. The amount of *energy* required depends on how long you want the sound to play. You asked how much *power* you would need to produce 60dB at 300Hz, so...

The answer is very simple, but useless. dB is a measure of relative power. Assuming a common reference level, and that all the electrical energy goes into making the sound, to produce 60dB of sound power you simply need 60dB of electrical power!

But what does that mean in practice? To get actual power you need to define your reference levels. Electrical signal levels are usually specified in [dBm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm), which is relative to 1mW. [Acoustic power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_power) in air is usually measured in dBSPL, which is relative to 1pW. So a sound power level of +60dB corresponds to an electric power level of -30dBm (1uW).

Great, so I might only need 1uW to produce a sound level of 60dB! Not quite. Firstly, the amount of sound that reaches a particular point in space depends on how far away it is from the source, the radiation pattern of the speaker and enclosure, and absorption by the air (which varies with humidity, temperature, frequency etc.). Secondly, real-world speakers have very low and poorly defined efficiency, so even taking into account all other factors the results will still be useless.

However you don't need to know the speaker's efficiency to get a useful answer. Speakers are commonly rated by [sensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker#Efficiency_vs._sensitivity), which is the sound level produced at a distance of 1m with 1W of input power. A typical small audio speaker might produce 90dB from 1W. In comparison, 60dB is -30dB or 1000 times less - so to produce 60dB you would need 1mW.

Speaker sensitivity is usually specified as an average over a range of frequencies. To get a more accurate answer for a particular frequency you need to examine (or measure) the speaker's frequency response. The graph below shows the frequency response of a typical 76mm (2") speaker. At 300Hz It produces 91dB from 1W, so should need just under 1mW to produce 60dB. Note that the response may be quite different when the speaker is placed in an enclosure.

[image: 76mm speaker frequency response]